# Eleventy - How to compile .yaml files (text not data) into html?

Tags: yaml, eleventy

I'm new using Eleventy, but I succeed in turning `.md` files into `.html`.
So far so good, even using templates/layouts.

**However, I've a problem I can't solve.**

Consider a bunch of `yaml` files (they are **not** `data` but `text`).

From:

```
src:
 - spec-1.0.0.yaml
 - spec-1.1.0.yaml
```

I'd like Eleventy to compile to:

```
_site:
 - spec-1.0.0/index.html
 - spec-1.1.0/index.html
```

...where `index.html` are my `base.njk` layout and my `yaml` text copy/paste in a `code` tag.

How to do so: Eleventy doesn't see/use my `yaml` files?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Eleventy doesn't process your `yaml` files because it has no idea what you want to do with them. YAML isn't a template language, and the data inside can be interpreted in many different ways.

If you want Eleventy to process `yaml` files by outputting `html` files with the contents of the `yaml` file inside some code, there are several methods, each with advantages and disadvantages.

### Custom Template Language

You can define a [custom template language](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/custom/) which tells Eleventy how to process files that aren't part of the default template languages.

This method requires the least amount of changes but isn't very flexible if your requirements change in the future. However, it does exactly what you said you wanted to do—convert every `yaml` file in your `src` folder to an `html` file in a `<code>` tag (I also added a `pre` tag for keeping whitespace).

In your `.eleventy.js` config file:

```js
// .eleventy.js

module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {

  // ...

  // tell eleventy to process .yaml files
  eleventyConfig.addTemplateFormats('yaml')
  // tell eleventy what to do with them
  eleventyConfig.addExtension('yaml', {
    compile: (inputContent) => {
      let output = `<!doctype html><html><body><pre><code>${inputContent}</code></pre></body></html>`
      return () => output
    },
  })

  // ...

}
```

This method works, but it's not convenient if you ever want to add more things to your markup.

### Data file and Pagination

You can create a [JavaScript data file](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-js/) in your `src/_data` directory that finds `.yaml` files and returns the content. Then you can [paginate the data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/) to generate pages.

This method means that you can use any template language of your choice or layouts to add styling, scripts, or other markup. You can even parse the YAML with `js-yaml` or something and render different things depending on the content inside.

```js
// src/_data/yamlFiles.js

const fs = require('fs/promises')

module.exports = async () => {
  const files = await fs.readdir('./src/')
  const yamlFiles = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith('.yaml'))

  const output = ( // read from each file
    await Promise.all(
      yamlFiles.map(async (file) => {
        const content = await fs.readFile(`./src/${file}`, 'utf8')
        return {
          file: file.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.'),
          content,
        }
      })
    )
  )
    // convert a list of objects to an object mapping filename to content
    .reduce((acc, { file, content }) => {
      acc[file] = content
      return acc
    }, {})

  return output
}
```

In `src/yamlFiles.njk` (or template language of choice, the filename doesn't matter):

```html
---
pagination:
    data: yamlFiles
    size: 1
    alias: filename
permalink: "{{filename}}/"
# layout: your_layout
---
{% set fileContent = yamlFiles[filename] %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <pre><code>{{ fileContent | safe }}</code></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're using this method, you may want to create a separate directory outside your `src` folder to store your YAML files. Just change the paths in `src/_data/yamlFiles.js`.